# Fork/Join do Java Funciona igual ao Fork do C?

Tags: java, c, paralelismo

Discutindo com um amigo sobre uma solução de calculo de matrizes que estamos desenvolvendo, surgiu a seguinte pergunta.

O funcionamento do Framework Fork/Join do Java é igual ao do C?

Lendo um pouco não consegui entender muito bem o funcionamento do C. Alguém poderia me ajudar nessa?

Answer (score 2):

O *fork* é uma função que é uma chamada de sistema. Ou seja, ela invoca o sistema operacional para fazer alguma tarefa que o usuário não pode.
No caso, o fork é usado para criar um novo processo em sistemas do tipo Unix, e isso só pode ser feito via fork.

Ao ser criado um processo por meio do fork, dizemos que esse novo processo é o filho, e o processo pai é aquele que usou o fork.

Para usar a chamada de sistema de criação de processos, simplesmente escrevemos fork(), sem passar argumento algum. Fazendo isso, o Sistema Operacional se encarrega do resto, e retorna um número. Este número é o pid (process identification, ou identificador de processos), e cada processo tem um valor diferente de pid, é como se fosse o RG, a identificação de cada processo.

Porém, ao armazenar esse retorno da função fork numa variável de nome `pid` do tipo `pid_t`, vemos que esse número de pid tem um comportamento especial:

*Dentro do processo filho, o pid tem valor 0.*

*Dentro do processo pai, o pid tem o valor do processo filho.*

*A `fork()` retorna um valor negativo, caso tenha ocorrido algum erro.*

Assim, para criarmos um programa e diferenciarmos o processo pai do filho, basta fazermos um teste com esse valor de retorno da `fork()`.
Primeiro, testamos se a `fork()` foi bem sucedida. Em seguida, fazemos `if (pid == 0)`, e isso só é verdade no processo filho. Ou seja, tudo dentro desse *if* só vai ser executado pelo processo filho, o pai não entra nessa condicional. E caso esse teste condicional seja falso, é porque o processo em vigor é o pai. Então, dentro do *else*, colocamos aquilo que será executado somente no processo pai.

Um exemplo de como implementar um fork em C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    pid_t pid;

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0) /*Se ocorer um erro*/
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    /**O getpid() retorna o pid do processo em execução.**/
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        //O código aqui dentro será executado no processo filho
        printf("pid do Filho: %d\n", getpid());
    }
    else
    {
        //O código neste trecho será executado no processo pai
        printf("pid do Pai: %d\n", getpid());
    }

    printf("Esta regiao sera executada por ambos processos\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    exit(0);
}
```

A conclusão é que o objetivo do fork e criar um processo filho a partir do processo pai, e trabalhar com os dois simultaneamente e usando tanto como as mesmas variáveis ou as suas próprias, assim você pode fazer com que sua aplicação consiga executar mais de uma tarefa.

PS: É necessário as duas bibliotecas `sys/types.h` e `unistd.h` do Unix, para poder trabalhar com a fork.

[Fonte.](http://www.programacaoprogressiva.net/2014/09/A-Chamada-de-Sistema-fork-Como-Criar-e-Gerenciar-Processos.html)

Comment: O problema todo é que estamos tentando implementar o equivalente em Java, Por isso a Duvida.

Comment: Se vc quiser fazer uma outra pergunta de como implementar o fork em java ou então vc pode dar uma olhada aqui na documentação do java https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html. Mas eu sugiro que vc faça outra pergunta msm.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que li do [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html), é um pouco diferente.

Em C, quando se faz o fork, você tem 2 processos, um pai e um filho. De posse do pid do filho, o processo pai pode fazer o join, quando o processo filho terminar.

Em Java, o algoritmo é similar, mas o funcionamento para o Sistema Operacional é diferente. O algoritmo é

```
se (a parte de trabalho for pequena o suficiente)
   faça o que tem que fazer
caso contrário
   divida o meu trabalho em duas partes
   execute as duas partes e espere pelo resultado
```

Exemplo retirado da [Universidade de Washington](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~djg/teachingMaterials/spac/grossmanSPAC_forkJoinFramework.html):

```
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask;

class Sum extends RecursiveTask<Long> {
    static final int SEQUENTIAL_THRESHOLD = 5000;

    int low;
    int high;
    int[] array;

    Sum(int[] arr, int lo, int hi) {
        array = arr;
        low   = lo;
        high  = hi;
    }

    protected Long compute() {
        if(high - low <= SEQUENTIAL_THRESHOLD) {
            long sum = 0;
            for(int i=low; i < high; ++i) 
                sum += array[i];
            return sum;
         } else {
            int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
            Sum left  = new Sum(array, low, mid);
            Sum right = new Sum(array, mid, high);
            left.fork();
            long rightAns = right.compute();
            long leftAns  = left.join();
            return leftAns + rightAns;
         }
     }

     static long sumArray(int[] array) {
         return ForkJoinPool.commonPool().invoke(new Sum(array,0,array.length));
     }
}
```

Nesse exemplo, você faz uma soma dos elementos de um Array. Se o array tiver mais que 5000 elementos, a tarefa será dividida. O método `compute` implementa o pseudo-código descrito.

[Exemplo de ordenação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveAction.html):

```
static class SortTask extends RecursiveAction {
    final long[] array; final int lo, hi;
    SortTask(long[] array, int lo, int hi) {
        this.array = array; this.lo = lo; this.hi = hi;
    }
    SortTask(long[] array) { this(array, 0, array.length); }
    protected void compute() {
        if (hi - lo < THRESHOLD)
            sortSequentially(lo, hi);
        else {
            int mid = (lo + hi) >>> 1;
            invokeAll(new SortTask(array, lo, mid),
                new SortTask(array, mid, hi));
            merge(lo, mid, hi);
        }
    }
    // implementation details follow:
   static final int THRESHOLD = 1000;
   void sortSequentially(int lo, int hi) {
       Arrays.sort(array, lo, hi);
   }
   void merge(int lo, int mid, int hi) {
       long[] buf = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, lo, mid);
       for (int i = 0, j = lo, k = mid; i < buf.length; j++)
           array[j] = (k == hi || buf[i] < array[k]) ?
               buf[i++] : array[k++];
   }
}
```

Primeiro você tem que escolher o tipo de `Task`. São duas opções:

- `RecusiveTask`: devolve um resultado após o fork
- `ActionTask`: não devolve um resultado após o fork

Segundo tem que implementar o método compute seguindo o pseudo-algoritmo, utilizando `invokeAll`, `compute`, `fork` e `join`.

Finalmente, você tem que usar um pool de threads chamado `ForkJoinPool`. Vi pelo menos duas formas:

```
ForkJoinPool.commonPool().invoke(task);
```

ou

```
ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
pool.invoke(task);
```

Por baixos dos panos, o java.util.Arrays.parallelSort usa Fork/Join API.